# View resizing causes loss of rect tag with XIB in Xcode 6.1

Tags: interface-builder, mkmapview, uitextview, xcode6, xib

I have several items in a view in a xib file. Amongst these are a UITextView and a MKMapView. I can successfully place the text view and the map view on the view, but when I try to resize one of these, the other looses its rect tag from the xib file. The net result is that the size of the view I'm not resizing goes to 0. E.g., before resizing in Xcode 6.1, in the xib file, it has:

```
            <textView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" fixedFrame="YES" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="x4f-Hr-uLZ">
                <rect key="frame" x="34" y="43" width="397" height="85"/>
                <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="14"/>
                <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits" autocapitalizationType="sentences"/>
            </textView>
            <mapView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" fixedFrame="YES" mapType="standard" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="4hk-wX-Agv">
                <rect key="frame" x="25" y="149" width="397" height="130"/>
            </mapView>
```

After resizing the text view, it has:

```
            <textView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" fixedFrame="YES" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="x4f-Hr-uLZ">
                <rect key="frame" x="34" y="43" width="397" height="89"/>
                <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="14"/>
                <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits" autocapitalizationType="sentences"/>
            </textView>
            <mapView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" fixedFrame="YES" mapType="standard" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="4hk-wX-Agv"/>
```

Note the loss of the rect tag from the mapView.

If I change the sizes within the xml xib file, no such problem occurs. Also, if I just reposition one of these views, there is no problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is at best a partial answer to my question. This seems to have to do with Autolayout and/or size classes. If I turn off Autolayout (and size classes), the problem goes away (as does Autolayout through IB).